# UserManager does not contain a definition for CreateIdentity

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to migrate this code to ASP.NET V5:

```
    public ClaimsIdentity GenerateUserIdentity(UserManager<User> manager, string authenticationType)
    {
        var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(this, authenticationType);
        ...
```

I'm getting the error `UserManager<User> does not contain a definition for CreateIdentity`

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: did you check for the Update of `Microsot.Aspnet.Identitly assembly` in nuget ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.usermanagerextensions.create(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 4):

To create a `ClaimsPrincipal` from a `TUser` object, you can import `IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>` in your own code and call `CreateAsync`:

```
var principal = await factory.CreateAsync(user);
```

Alternatively, you can also use `UserManager<TUser>.GetClaimsAsync` - which is what `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>` uses behind the scenes - and create a `ClaimsIdentity` yourself:

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(await manager.GetClaimsAsync(user), authenticationType);
```