# what is the substitute of CreateIdentityAsync method in Asp.Net Core 1.0 RTM?

Tags: asp.net-core-1.0

In ASP.Net Core1.0 RTM, I'm trying to create Identity using this method:

```
userManager.CreateIdentityAsync()
```

but I get this error:

> 'UserManager' doesnot contain a definition for 'CreateIdentityAsync'.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UserManager does not contain a definition for CreateIdentity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514997/usermanager-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-createidentity)

Answer (score 5):

You can try [IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory](http://aspnet-docs-example.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNet/Identity/IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory-TUser/)

```
ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = await _claimsPrincipalFactory.CreateAsync(user);
((ClaimsIdentity) claimsPrincipal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("user_id", user.Id.ToString()));
```

Comment: I suggest have a look to the next link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.iuserclaimsprincipalfactory-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score -1):

I use `ClaimsIdentityFactory()`. Here is my code:

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity>
GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, 
                          string AuthenticationType)
    {
        var factory = new ClaimsIdentityFactory<ApplicationUser>();
        return await factory.CreateAsync(manager, this, AuthenticationType);
    }
```

Comment: There is no ClaimsIdentityFactory in Core. Only a UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.   Likewise, there is no ClaimsIdentityAsync, only CreateUserPrincipalAsync.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: `signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);`